# Prisma schema multiple relations between models

Tags: prisma

I have 3 models:

```
model User {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  session       Session?    @relation(fields: [sessionId], references: [id])
  sessionId     Int?
  @@unique([sessionId, name])
}

model Session {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  code          String      @unique
  players       User[]
}

model Message {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  message       String
}
```

I want users to be able to create messages.

A session can have many messages.
A user can have many messages.
A message can have one session.
A message can have one user.

I tried adding the relations:

```
model User {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  messages      Message[]   @relation(fields: [messageId], references: [id])
  messageId     Int
  session       Session?    @relation(fields: [sessionId], references: [id])
  sessionId     Int?
  @@unique([sessionId, name])
}

model Session {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  code          String      @unique
  players       User[]
  messages      Message[]
}

model Message {
  id            Int         @id       @default(autoincrement())
  message       String
  user          Session?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        Int
  session       Session?    @relation(fields: [sessionId], references: [id])
  sessionId     Int?
}
```

But this gives the (logical) error:

> Error validating model "Message": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `user` and `session` in model `Message` both refer to `Session`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation().

I've read the docs > https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations but I cannot figure out the syntax/convention for the named fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two fields with the same relation model, you need to add name atribute to them:

Simple add the "yourname" before the "fields"

```
model LanguageFlagLocale {
  id             Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  localeId       Int
  languageFlagId Int
  languageFlag   LanguageFlag @relation("languageFlag", fields: [languageFlagId], references: [id])
  locale         LanguageFlag @relation("locale", fields: [localeId], references: [id])
}

model LanguageFlag {
  id                    Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  LanguageFlag          LanguageFlagLocale[]    @relation("languageFlag")
  LanguageFlagLocale    LanguageFlagLocale[]    @relation("locale")
}
```

Also, it looks like you have a mistake in your model:

```
  user          Session?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        Int
```

Looks like it should be `user          User?`

Comment: While you are correct, I did find an underlying issue which caused me not to figure out why it wasn't working. In my `message` model I define `user` as a `session`, not as a `user`.  Once I fixed that it all clicked :)